# NodeJS + Keycloak without express

Tags: node.js, express, keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

I'm trying to secure my Node.JS app with Keycloak, but my app doesn't use express. I have searched extensively, but to me, it seems like this is impossible, at least with the libraries provided officially by Keycloak. (“keycloak without express” just turns up *no results at all*)

I'm somewhat new to the keycloack ecosystem though, and would be delighted if anyone could offer some solution to my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keycloak offers [Node.js adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_nodejs_adapter). Yes, examples in the doc are for express.js, but nothing stopping you to use it in any Node.js app (of course it depends how that Node.js app is implemented).

Anyway, Keycloak is not based on any legacy protocol, but on the OIDC standard, so you can use any OIDC library. It really doesn't need to have 'keycloak' in the name. You can start from [OIDC certified libraries](https://openid.net/developers/certified/).

Comment: Yep, figured that would be the case. In my case, `keycloak-connect` really doesn't work at all, so I've just settled for using `openid-client`. Thanks!

Comment: The 'node.js adapter' requires the use of express middleware, I don't know how you would go about that without express. It does not seem a node.js adapter to me